# Geometry node support store string attribute?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make a scatter func to generate foliage or instance to UE, so i need to save scale, orient and a string reference to unreal mesh, like houdini engine' unreal_instance, but i found blender GN is not supported to store string attributes:
[image]

does string attribute is on roadmap? or i can use some other way to achieve my thoughts?

Comment: There are no Blender developers on this site so you'll have to look on https://developer.blender.org/ to see what's coming.

Comment: In what format are you exporting data from Blender?

Comment: did u ever try animation nodes?

Comment: @John Eason
 i post on that site before on another topic, but their developer told me ask question here...

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys
i made a addon to save my customized point format

Comment: I don't understand the issue then. What's the problem with storing strings if you are using Python? You can do pretty much whatever you imagine with strings in Python. You can store strings to be exported in so many places, I don't even know where to begin. How do you generate and use the string?

Comment: @willFederer Ok, but I was just pointing out that no-one here knows what the developers have on the roadmap. Anyway you've had several suggestions here on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it wherever you like if you are using Python. You can retrieve it from any node. For example, you could make an output for geometry nodes node group:

[image]

Comment: Thx for your explanation,  what i need is not just a string standalone,  but should be a point attribute, for example, i make total thirty points, ten points as apple, ten as banana, ten as orange, and i need to export them to UE instancing, so i need a way to associate every point with UE apple,banana and orange asset reference string...

Comment: Named attribute's name is a string. It is stored.

Comment: Marynas, I think what OP is saying is they want an attribute that contains a string for each point.

Comment: @NoobieStClair Named attribute can be a boolean so it can be a string that some points have(True) and don't have(False).

Comment: **Strings are constants** - there are no string fields currently. You can't have a string per point. You can have some kind of integer per point, and each integer could mean some string - you then could have some kind of a list of strings in Python and use the stored integers in an attribute as indices of those strings.